# AdvancedSearch method not searching subfolders?

Tags: vba, outlook

I have the below code in my "ThisOutlookSession" object:

The purpose is to, upon application startup, to filter mail received while the Outlook client is closed. To do this, I am using the `AdvancedSearch` method. The results of the search are printed to the immediate window. Only mail that is in the `Inbox` is captured in the search, but not anything that had a client rule routing the applicable mail to a subfolder within the Inbox (which should also be captured by the search given the option `SearchSubFolders` has been set to `True`.

Does this have something to do with client rule processing vs. application events ordering?

If so, how can I search all the subfolders of the `Inbox` in order to capture all mail received after a certain time?

```
Option Explicit
Public blnSearchComp As Boolean

' Code in ThisOutlookSession


Private Sub Application_AdvancedSearchComplete(ByVal SearchObject As Search)
' https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.application.advancedsearch
' Code should be in a class module such as ThisOutlookSession

    Debug.Print "The AdvancedSearchComplete Event fired"
    If SearchObject.Tag = "Process_New_Items" Then
        'm_SearchComplete = True`   ' Use Option Explicit.
        blnSearchComp = True
    End If
  
End Sub

Private Sub Application_Startup()
        
    Dim dmi As MailItem
    Dim timeFol As Folder
    
    Dim timeFilter As String
    Dim lastclose As String
    Dim utcdate As Date
    Dim strFilter As String
    
    Dim i As Object
    
    Dim strScope As String
    Dim SearchObject As Search
        
    Set dmi = CreateItem(olMailItem)
    Set timeFol = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderNotes)
    
    timeFilter = "[Subject] = 'App Close Time'"
    
    For Each i In timeFol.Items.Restrict(timeFilter)
        lastclose = i.CreationTime
    Next i
    Debug.Print lastclose
    
    utcdate = dmi.PropertyAccessor.LocalTimeToUTC(lastclose)
    
    'strFilter = "@SQL=""urn:schemas:httpmail:datereceived"" >= '" & Format(utcdate, "dd mmm yyyy hh:mm") & "'"
    strFilter = "urn:schemas:httpmail:datereceived >= " & "'" & utcdate & "'"
    Debug.Print strFilter
    
    strScope = "'" & Session.Folders(1).Folders("Inbox") & "'"
    Debug.Print strScope
    
    strScope = "'" & Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox) & "'"
    Debug.Print strScope
    
    strScope = "'Inbox'"
    Debug.Print strScope
    
    Set SearchObject = AdvancedSearch(Scope:=strScope, Filter:=strFilter, SearchSubFolders:=True, Tag:="Process_New_Items")
    
    ' 2022-07-01 Eureka!
    blnSearchComp = False
    ' Otherwise remains True.
    ' Search would work once until Outlook restarted.
    
    While blnSearchComp = False
        DoEvents
        ' Code should be in a class module such as ThisOutlookSession
        Debug.Print "Wait a few seconds. Ctrl + Break if needed."
    Wend
    
    Debug.Print "SearchObject.results.count: " & SearchObject.Results.Count
    
    For Each i In SearchObject.Results
        If TypeName(i) = "MailItem" Then
            Process_MailItem i
            Debug.Print i.ReceivedTime, i.Subject
        Else: End If
    Next i
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Add a `.Folders("subfolder with applicable items")` to the scope to confirm the subfolder is directly accessible.

Comment: You could as well run `Application_Startup` manually, as is, to see if the moved items became available later.

Answer (score 0):

The third parameter (`SearchSubFolders`) allows you to specify whether to include subfolders to the search results (scope) or not. Also you need to specify the scope correctly. Here you specify in what folders you would like to search for items. The `FolderPath` property of Outlook folders helps you do that  correctly.

```
Scope = "'" & Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).FolderPath & "'"
```

Read more about the `AdvancedSearch` method in the [Advanced search in Outlook programmatically: C#, VB.NET](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2012/05/31/outlook-search-csharp-vbnet/) article.

Comment: The scope worked identically employing the `FolderPath` property as when the scope simply was: `strScope = "'Inbox'"`. Both fail to capture mail that arrives to subfolders within the `Inbox` via Outlook rules. The third parameter has remained set to `True` as it was earlier.

Comment: Try to run the code manually to make sure such items were already moved to a subfolder. There is a chance items are received asynchronously when the code is run.

Comment: running the code manually from `ThisOutlookSession` worked. I am now going to try and find a way for the event to be triggered after the client rule processing has occurred. Could that be the issue? The only problem is mail that is routed to subfolders via a client rule.